# Filter a query then get a row by id with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to get a user by id only if they don't have `deleted=0`. I tried

```
user = User.query.filter_by(deleted=0).get(id)
```

but got an error. How do I filter the query and get by id?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/flask-sqlalchemy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 831, in get
    return self._get_impl(ident, loading.load_on_ident)
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/flask-sqlalchemy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 864, in _get_impl
    return fallback_fn(self, key)
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/flask-sqlalchemy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 177, in load_on_ident
    q._get_condition()
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/flask-sqlalchemy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 350, in _get_condition
    "get", order_by=False, distinct=False)
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/flask-sqlalchemy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 368, in _no_criterion_condition
    self._no_criterion_assertion(meth, order_by, distinct)
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/flask-sqlalchemy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 365, in _no_criterion_assertion
    "Query with existing criterion. " % meth)
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Query.get() being called on a Query with existing criterion.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the error says, `get` only works if you haven't filtered the query. If you want to filter, filter by `id` as well and use `first`.

```
user = User.query.filter_by(id=id, deleted=0).first()
```